# Excel VBA, looping to find empty cell and add combobox value to it

Tags: vba, excel

So far what I have is this :

```
Dim Check As Long

Check = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = Check To 1 Step -1
If Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
  Range("B" & i).Value = ComboBox2.Value
End If
Next i
```

Essentially I am trying to add multiple comboboxes and text boxes to the next empty lines and I think that would be with offsets as well.

Comment: Are there formulas that could return an empty string (e.g. `""`) in column B? If you are simply looking for the the first blank cell then offset 1 row from `check`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, there are no formulas, just using VBA to find the next blank row and add input from multiple comboboxes and text boxes.

Comment: 1) I was asking if there could be zero-length strings returned by formulas in column B; e.g. `if this, "", that)`. You've said No there is not so no problem there.

Comment: 2) you are not looking for the first blank cell; you are going to the bottom of the populated cells and working upwards looking for a blank cell with `Step -1`. If you want to find the first blank cell underneath all of the populated cells in column B then use `Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ComboBox2.Value` That is the same as going to the bottom of column B then hitting [ctrl]+[▲] then tapping [▼]. In other words, the first blank cell below the populated cells in column B.

Comment: Don't know who down-voted you but I've attempted to reverse it with my own up-vote. It's not a bad question but it does seem like you copied the code from somewhere else without understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of avoiding 'drive-by answers' through comments try this.

```
cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = ComboBox2.Value
```

That should replace **all** of your code in a private worksheet code sub. If it is **not**  a private worksheet code sheet then,

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
   .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = ComboBox2.Value
end with
```

... in a public module code sheet.

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful.